# JQuery Data Tables "scrollY" Glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My jquery data table is duplicating the sorting icons as shown below. This is due to `"scrollY": "450px",`. If I remove this line then the icons dissapear in the first column. Can anybody help?

[image]

JQuery initialization:

```
$( ".dynamic-table" ).DataTable({
    "scrollY": "450px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 500, -1], [10, 50, 500, "All"]]
});
```

Comment: Show your html ... its working normally  https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/8/

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on my DataTables implementation and I saw just what you're referring to. I don't know exactly why it's showing twice. I could get the second set of icons to disappear using this:

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

I would think that this would also hide the normal icons, but on my side it didn't.

**EDIT**

```
.ui-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried out this CSS but I am still left with the icons. :(

Comment: @Nic Showing the table as well as the part of the script you use to instantiate DataTables for this table is really the only way we'll be able to help better. You can also try the edit above.